# seleccionar un option con dos consultas para modificación jsp

Tags: java, jsp

tengo un problema, como hacer para seleccionar un option con un valor que ya  traigo de una consulta filtrada, si ese option lo lleno con otra consulta de un catalogo.
Y lo único que me hace es duplicarme el campo.
como lo muestra la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que uso es el sig:

```
out.println("<select class='form-control input-sm' id='proyecto' name='proyecto'>");

out.println("<option value=''>Seleccionar... </option>");
                        out.println("<option value='vacio'>Ninguno </option>");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

                                           while (rs.next()) 
                                           {                                                 

             out.println("<option>"+rs.getString(2)+"</option>");                                                                                                                                                                                                   

                                             if(rs.getString(2).equalsIgnoreCase(proyecto)){                                                     
                                                 out.println("<option selected>"+rs.getString(2)+"</option>");                                                                                                                                                           

                                                }                                                                                                                                                    
                                           }

                                           out.println("</select>");
```

Es `jsp` y `struts`

si alguien me puede orientar soy nuevo en java.

Comment: Parece que haces dos consultas en dos lugares diferentes. Si entiendo bien mandas a llamar datos de otro option pero en el que los vas a poner ya tienes datos. Me suena a que necesitas comprobar uno por uno si ya existe y no ponerlo para que no salga repetido.

Comment: O en otro caso has solo una consulta y pasa esos mismos datos al otro option.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así

```
while (rs.next()) {                                                 


        if(rs.getString(2).equalsIgnoreCase(proyecto)){                                                     
            out.println("<option selected>"+rs.getString(2)+"</option>");                                                                                                                                                           

        } else {
            out.println("<option>"+rs.getString(2)+"</option>"); 
}                                                                                                                                                   
   }
```

Comment: Ya lo hice así pero me duplica el campo, si me lo selecciona pero me lo duplica y es lo que no quiero..
Otra alternativa

Comment: Es imposible que te lo duplique con el código que te puse arriba. Estás segura que lo probaste así?

Comment: Seguro* xD ....